# JAVACC && JJTree (.jjt) Inserting || symbol into tree when parsing two tokens

Tags: java, tree, javacc

For e.g. A B && C Tree should be like this  (A || B) && (C). this should be like this. I tried out but every time extra || is added like this A || B || && C. this generates the wrong tree every time.

Code i do it like this

```
LOOKAHEAD((simpleTerm())+)

   (
       simpleTerm()
  {
     jjtthis.setValue("||");
   }
   )+
```

****Note simpleTerm could be &ltSTRING&gt or &ltQuotedString&gt****

How can i insert || symbol into tree so it form tree like this A || B && C.?

How can i insert token image into tree using javacode ?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like the following

```
void Conjunction() #void :
{ }
{
  Disjunction()
  (  "&&"
     Disjunction()  
     {jjtThis.setValue( "&&" );} #BinOp(2)
  )*
}

void Disjunction() #void :
{}
{
  SimpleTerm()
  (  
     SimpleTerm()  
     {jjtThis.setValue( "||" );} #BinOp(2)
  )*
}

void SimpleTerm() :
{Token t ;}
{
    (t=<STRING> | t=<QUOTEDSTRING>)
    {jjtThis.setValue( t.image ) ;}
}
```

Comment: Thanx for such a nyc response. Could it be possible to lave lest associativity and tree formed is left associative

Comment: I think && and || are already treated as left associative in my answer.